# Replace character in a column by the character in the adjacent column in R?

Tags: r

Hi guys I would need to replace a character in a dataframe by the character in the adjacent column:
So i want to replace the character "uncultured" in column genus, by the right family name in the column family. I gave you some example data, that s how my columns look like, despite there are more than 1300 columns in my real data.
What I could replace where the NA values in the column genus by the right family, but than I got stuck:

```
molekc$genus[is.na(molekc$genus)] <- molekc$family[is.na(molekc$genus)]

family <- c("choreo","Nassophorea","choreo","Phyllopharyngea","Choreo","Oligo")

genus <- c("choreo","uncultured","choreo","uncultured","Pithites","Tintinnopsis")

stack <- data.frame(family,genus, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: `molekc$genus[molekc$genus == "uncultured"] <- molekc$family[molekc$genus == "uncultured"]`

Comment: @Aurèle thanks, that works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution with ifelse:

```
stack$genus <- with(stack, ifelse(genus =='uncultured', family, genus))
```

Or, you could do this for both NA's and 'uncultured':

```
stack$genus <- with(stack, ifelse(genus =='uncultured' | is.na(genus), family, genus))
```